# Matplotlib renders wrong ticks on the y axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to render specified ticks on the *y* axis using `matplotlib` Python package. The library for some reason renders more ticks than I give it to render and use scientific notation for them. For me it seems like a bug in the library, I was able to reproduce the issue on more devices. Is there a workaround?

The source code to reproduce the issue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
plt.xlim(0, 1000)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.ylim(20, 200)
plt.yticks([20, 28, 39, 54, 75, 110, 150, 200])
plt.gca().get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(mticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False))
plt.gca().get_yaxis().set_tick_params(which='minor', width=0)
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.close()
```

The rendered graph:

[image: Rendered graph]

**EDIT**
Calling `plt.gca().get_yaxis().clear()` after the `plt.yscale('log')` seems to solve the issue.

Comment: They are minor ticks. Use `plt.minorticks_off()`

Comment: Did you try turning the minor ticks off?  `set_minor_formatter(mticker.NullFormatter())`

Comment: They haven't been minor ticks, but the original axis after the `plt.yscale('log')` call, before changing the formatter. Clearing it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting `plt.yscale('log')` out, seems to remove scientific notation from the y axis while keeping the desired tick values.

[image: zeroth example]

If you still need it, putting `plt.yscale('log')` after `plt.ylim()` and `plt.yticks()` seems to work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
plt.xlim(0, 1000)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylim(20, 200)
plt.yticks([20, 28, 39, 54, 75, 110, 150, 200])
plt.yscale('log')
plt.gca().get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(mticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False))
plt.gca().get_yaxis().set_tick_params(which='minor', width=0)
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.close()
```

[image: first example]

To replace 100 for 10^2, I commented the first `plt.gca()` line:

[image: second example]

Comment: Thanks, your suggestions give me the right direction. Calling `plt.gca().get_yaxis().clear()` after `plt.yscale('x')` seems to solve the problem.